# Обработчик ошибки BadData (CSVhelper)

Tags: c#, winforms, консоль

Нужно написать обработчик событий BadData, я не знаю как, не давно изучаю этот ЯП. Буду рад любой помощи! Заранее спасибо Всем, кто откликнется. Подробнее об ошибке: 
An unhandled exception of type 'CsvHelper.BadDataException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll

Additional information: You can ignore bad data by setting BadDataFound to null.

Как я понял, нужно создать обработчик события, который будет приравнивать BadDataFound к нулю, но как это сделать... Думаю, что можно через try-catch, но не изучил этот пункт :c

```csharp
 public static class SSDs
        {
            public static List<SSD> GetSSDValues()
            {
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "SSD_UserBenchmarks.csv");
                using (var reader0 = new StreamReader(filePath))
                using (var csv0 = new CsvReader(reader0, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    var ssds = new List<SSD>();
                    csv0.Read();
                    csv0.ReadHeader();
                    while (csv0.Read())
                    {
                        var ssd = new SSD
                        {
                            Type = csv0.GetField<string>("Type"),
                            Brand = csv0.GetField<string>("Brand"),
                            Model = csv0.GetField<string>("Model"),
                            Benchmark = csv0.GetField<float>("Benchmark")
                        };
                        ssds.Add(ssd);
                    }
                    return ssds;
                }
            }
        }

        // Sozdanie classa dlya parsinga Type/Brand/Model/Benchmark'a SSD;
        public class SSD
        {
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Brand { get; set; }
            public string Model { get; set; }
            public float Benchmark { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Вот, [посмотрите](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55181148/csvhelper-baddatafound-in-a-valid-csv)

Comment: Огромное спасибо, код требовал пару строк, как я и думал) Спасибо большое! :3 <3

Comment: @aepot Не подскажите как пометить "Решенным" мой вопрос?

Comment: @aepot или вы ответьте, я помечу, как решенное, чтобы вам баллы засчитало и ответ был, для тех, кто будет искать, вдруг не увидят)

Comment: Без ответа никак. Но мой комментарий не ответ, а указание, что ответ уже существует, а вы просто его не нашли. Вы можете дописать свой ответ, вставив в него часть кода с решением. Спустя какое-то время система позволит отметить его как принятый, репутация при ответе на свои вопросы не начисляется. Или вы можете удалить вопрос или вообще ничего не делать.